# Separate users from admin users in different databases on the same server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I use ASP.NET Identity and want to achieve following databases setup:

- Database that has all application data, including User's accounts
- Separate database that will only contain Administrators accounts.

This is what I came up so far, but I get an exception in `Program.cs` on line `app.Run()`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Identity.Application'

[image]

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyApp.Landing.Extensions;
using MyApp.Landing.Areas.Identity.Data;
using MyApp.DAL.DbContexts;
using MyApp.Landing.Describers;
using MyApp.Landing.Automapper.Profiles;
using MyApp.DAL.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using MyApp.DAL.Roles;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString") ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Connections is not set in the environment variables. \"ConnectionString\" is empty");

var adminConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AdminConnectionString") ??
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Connections is not set in the environment variables. \"AdminConnectionString\" is empty");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AdminDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(adminConnectionString));

builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, UserRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure identity for admins
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationAdmin, AdminRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AdminDbContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationAdmin>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


builder.Services.RegisterRepositories();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
{
    config.AddProfile<RegistrationProfile>();
});

// Add Razor Pages services
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

`AuthDbContext`:

```cs
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AuthDbContext()
    {
    }

    public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}

public class AuthDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AuthDbContext>
{
    public AuthDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Connections is not set in the environment variables. \"ConnectionString\" is empty");
        }

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AuthDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new AuthDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Migrations are created and applied just fine, with creation of separate databases

I'm expecting to manage admin user's credentials separately, in different database

I've tried setting authentication schemes like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("UserCookieScheme")
    .AddCookie("UserCookieScheme", options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("AdminCookieScheme")
    .AddCookie("AdminCookieScheme", options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Admin/Account/AccessDenied";
    });
```

Setting `SignInManager` like this:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, UserRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure identity for admins
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationAdmin, AdminRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AdminDbContext>()
    .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationAdmin>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Why would you want to separate admin users into a different database though?

Comment: @DavidG Just want to separate it this way

Comment: Yes but why? It adds complexity but nothing else.

Comment: @DavidG Well, security for example. I don't know for a fact if it actually affects security in a good way, but I decided to try to separate admin users out of curiosity. Is it possible?

Comment: Actually it probably affects security in a bad way because hackers will now have more ways to infiltrate your system